# How to delete a child domain row in grails

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am saving data to my entry meeting table as well as entry meeting details table which is a child table of entry meeting table. But When I want to delete only a child table record it's giving a error. I can't understand what to do. I am using grails 2.1.0. Can anyone please help me on this please ?!!! Here is my code below :

my parent domain >>>

```
class AdtEntryMeeting {
    static mapping = {
        table('ADT_ENTRY_MEETING')
        version(false)
        entryMeetingDetails cascade: 'all'
    }
    String meetingVenue
    Date meetingDate = new Date()
    String meetingTime
    long CREATED_BY=0
    Date CREATED_DATE=new Date()
    long UPDATED_BY=0
    Date UPDATED_DATE=new Date()
    static hasMany = [entryMeetingDetails: AdtEntryMeetingDetails]
    static constraints = {
        meetingVenue(nullable: false, blank: false)
        meetingDate(nullable: false)
        meetingTime(nullable: false, blank: false)
        CREATED_BY(nullable:true)
        CREATED_DATE(nullable:true)
        UPDATED_BY(nullable: true)
        UPDATED_DATE(nullable: true)
    }
    String toString(){
        return id
    }
}
```

my child domain >>>

```
class AdtEntryMeetingDetails {
    static mapping = {
        table('ADT_ENTRY_MEETING_DETAILS')
        version(false)
    }
    AuditFirm auditPack
    AuditorDtl auditor
    String meetingSubject
    String responsiblePerson
    AdtEntryMeeting entryMeeting
    static constraints = {
        auditPack(nullable: false, blank: false)
        auditor(nullable: false, blank: false)
        meetingSubject(nullable: false, blank: false)
        responsiblePerson(nullable: false, blank: false)
        entryMeeting(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
    String toString(){
        return auditPack
    }
}
```

my action to delete >>>

```
if(params[isDelete + detailsCounter] == 'delete'){
                def entryMeetingDetailsDelete = AdtEntryMeetingDetails.get(Long.parseLong(params[entryMeetingDetailsId + detailsCounter]))
                entryMeetingDetailsDelete.delete()
            }else{
                def entryMeetingDetailsEdit = AdtEntryMeetingDetails.get(Long.parseLong(params[entryMeetingDetailsId + detailsCounter]))
                entryMeetingDetailsEdit.properties['auditPack'] = AuditFirm.get(Long.parseLong(params[auditPack + detailsCounter]))
                entryMeetingDetailsEdit.properties['auditor'] = AuditorDtl.get(Long.parseLong(params[auditor + detailsCounter]))
                entryMeetingDetailsEdit.properties['meetingSubject'] = params[meetingSubject + detailsCounter]
                entryMeetingDetailsEdit.properties['responsiblePerson'] = params[responsiblePerson + detailsCounter]
                adtEntryMeetingInstance.addToEntryMeetingDetails(entryMeetingDetailsEdit)
            }
```

the error I am getting >>>

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

Comment: if the `static mapping cascade` doesn't work, you can try to use [belongsTo](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first remove the reference from parent and then delete the child

e.g

```
def entryMeetingDetailsDelete = AdtEntryMeetingDetails.get(Long.parseLong(params[entryMeetingDetailsId + detailsCounter]))

adtEntryMeetingInstance.removeFromAdtEntryMeetingDetails(entryMeetingDetailsDelete)
 entryMeetingDetailsDelete.delete()
```